# Java Script Java SocketServer Integration

Tags: javascript

I Have JavaScript Code which sends a request to small java socket program,
JavaScript code runs at Jav EE Application at domain when The Small Java code runs at diffrenr domain. Now I Want to send request and then receive response from The Small program, but I get an error on my browser FireFox:

> "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows
>   reading the remote resource at"

where When I run code om IE ..its okay

java Script Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //  <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
                var getJSON = function (url, successHandler, errorHandler) {
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

                        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest === "undefined")
                        XMLHttpRequest = function () {
                            try {
                                return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
                            }
                            catch (e) {
                            }
                            try {
                                return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
                            }
                            catch (e) {
                            }
                            try {
                                return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                            }
                            catch (e) {
                            }

                            throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");
                        };

                    xhr.open('get', url, true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

                        var data;

                        if (xhr.readyState === 4) { 

                            if (xhr.status === 200) {

                                data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);


                                var imgDoc = document.getElementById("search_sources_form:image");

                                imgDoc.value = data['img'];

                                remoteChangeCommand();

                                xhr.abort();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.send();
                };
                function scanData() {

                    getJSON('http://10.0.10.59:2000/image=1;', function (data) {
                        alert('Your public IP address is: ' + data);
                    }, function (status) {
                        alert('Something went wrong.');
                    });
                }
```

Comment: which means IE doesnt implement same origin policy properly :)

Answer (score 0):

Enable cross-origin requests for the domain that is blocking and it will work.

Example below is taken from html5boilerplate's [apache server config](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache). Visit the links for detailed information.

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Cross-origin requests                                              |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Allow cross-origin requests.
# https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
# http://enable-cors.org/
# http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com/"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Okay>>but what about using glassfish as App. Server..how can i Set  Cross-origin requests